# Is it possible to store something online in a C++ repl?

Tags: cloud, read-eval-print-loop, replit

I only have a very limited knowledge of how the site itself works, so bear with me.

I'm trying to create a multi-player game using `repl.it`.

Not a real-time game with actual interactions between players, but just something where progress can be saved and loaded back to repl. I was wondering whether it is possible to save something to the repl files themselves (like a write-read sort of thing) and be able to keep it saved even when the repl is stopped.

Any advice on how to approach this?

If I left out context, let me know and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Repl.it Database! https://docs.repl.it/misc/database

[Repl.it Q&A](https://repl.it/talk/ask) and also [Discord](http://repl.it/discord) is a great place to ask Repl.it questions.